# ios/coredata/nfetchresultscontroller. How do I get a tableview of records to update after adding a new one

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to use the delegate pattern to get a tableview of records to update after adding a new record.

I have the code for nsfetched results controller in the tableview controller.  The table is subscribed as a delegate to nsfetchedresults controller.  I have the save code in the add new record controller.  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you.

```
table view controller:
header:
@interface IDTVC : UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

source:
#pragma mark - Fetched Results Controller

-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController==nil){
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest= [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        //access the single managed object context through model singleton
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [IDModel sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;
        //fetch request requires an entity description - we're only interested in IDModel managed objects
        NSEntityDescription *entity =[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Dare" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        fetchRequest.entity=entity;
        //we'll order the IDModel ID Model objects in name sort order
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor,nil];
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors=sortDescriptors;

        self.fetchedResultsController=[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
 //       self.fetchedResultsController.delegate=self;

        [self.fetchedResultsController setDelegate:self];

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@,%@",error,[error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    }
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
//following supposed to be sufficient for delegate pattern to work
-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
//change
}

AddRecord Controller

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

    self.managedObjectContext = [IDModel sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;;
    // Helpers

    NSString *name = self.textField.text;
    NSString *sub = self.subField.text;

 //    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:name message:@"Your record needs a name." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    NSLog(@"save triggered");
    if (name && name.length) {
        // Create Entity
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"newitem" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        // Initialize Record
        NSManagedObject *record = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        // Populate Record
        [record setValue:name forKey:@"name"];
        [record setValue:sub forKey:@"sub"];

     //   [record setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"createdAt"];

        // Save Record
        NSError *error = nil;

        if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Dismiss View Controller
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            ;


        } else {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Unable to save record.");
                NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
            }

            // Show Alert View
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Your record could not be saved." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
        }

    } else {
        // Show Alert View
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Your item needs a name." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
}
//dismiss keyboard
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan:withEvent:");
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.title = @"Add Item";
    [IDModel sharedInstance];

    self.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
}
```

Do I need [self.tableView reloadData]; somewhere or shouldn't the delegate pattern handle the update?

Is there a problem with putting the save in the add view controller and the nsfetchresultscontroller code in the tableview?  Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that edit didn't go through… Use Lee's answer, but add the fourth `FetchedResultsControllerDelegate` method:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
    didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
        atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex
            forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex];

    switch(type)
    {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        {
            [self.tableView insertSections:indexSet
                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        {
            [self.tableView deleteSections:indexSet
                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            [self.tableView reloadSections:indexSet
                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to your controllerDidChangeContent delegate method, you will also need the controllerWillChangeContent which will kick off the table view update. Then in controllerDidChangeContent you will have to end the updates on the table view.

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
[tableView beginUpdates];
}
-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
[tableView endUpdates];
}
```

You will also need another delegate method that actually handles each updating action. Below:

```
-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
 switch (type)
{
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.row] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:newIndexPath.row] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.row] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        [tableView moveSection:indexPath.row toSection:newIndexPath.row];
        break;

    default:
        NSAssert(FALSE, @"what is this?");
        break;
}
}
```

Comment: Tried that (putting switch method in tableview controller) but still having same problem.  The table shows a new record (i.e. increments list of records by one) but repeats the last record instead of adding a new one.  If you have a record Joe, and add a new one, Bob it will show two records, both Joe.  Not until you close simulator and rebuild do you see Bob.  Still at a loss.  Could it have anything to do with where I am putting save method i.e. in add view controller?  Should it be in table view controller?

Comment: Have you tried adding [self.tableView reloadData] right after this code in the save method?  [record setValue:sub forKey:@"sub"];

Comment: I just added the fourth protocol method: `controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:`. Try again if that helps.